# c++, No symbol "i" in current context. gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

I am using....GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-83.el6)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int i = 40;
   cout << "Hello\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you compile?

Comment: You did not use i, probably the compiler removed it (action  ? elide ?elision ?)... try adding i to cout.

Comment: g++ -ggdb main.cpp

Comment: addding i to cout works. thanks. my dumb teacher had us following a tutorial that tells us to set a break then do p i, maybe that worked for an older of gdb but not anymore

Comment: It has nothing to do with gdb. Compiler could optimized that i away, but should not do that, if optimization is disabled. What exactly did you do. Just set a breakpoint (where) and print i? Did you run your code to main before printing?

Comment: 1) g++ -ggdb main.cpp 2) gdb a.out 3) list 3)break 6 4) p i

Comment: You can not print i, until you run the program. Try "start" command. Then print i.

Comment: sorry i forgot to include that between 3 and 4 i already tried running the program. I asked my instructing and he actually thinks it has something to do with gdb not being fully caught up to g++ 5.2.0, although he isn't even sure.

Comment: actually dbrank0 it had everything to do with gdb, i was using the wrong version haha

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i needed to add the followning lines to my .bash_profile

```
source /opt/Modules/init/bash
module load gcc/5.2.0
module load gdb/7.11
```